# Is there ever a reason for a php file to have executable permissions?

Tags: php, filesystems, file-permissions

When running the function `is_executable()` on a PHP file, it returns `false`. This begs the question, is there ever a case to set the permissions one way or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

If you use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of command line scripts (and they're flagged as executable) then they can  be executed directly using `exec()`